# Terraform GCP - create allUses IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

I'm trying to create Google IAM that will add `allUsers` to the role `roles/run.invoker`

I tried to do do it with:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "all_users_access" {
  project = var.project
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member   = "allUsers"
}
```

But Unfortunately, I get error:

```
Policy members must be prefixed of the form '\u003ctype\u003e:\u003cvalue\u003e', where \u003ctype\u003e is 'domain', 'group', 'serviceAccount', or 'user'."
```

So I tried with `group` prefix, but then I got an error that gets me puzzled as it is in contradiction with the previous:

```
Error setting IAM policy for project "bt-dev-001": googleapi: Error 400: Member type allUsers should be used without prefix., badReques
```

I'm using terraform version `4.16.0`

Does anyone know how to do that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, It occurs that IAM roles for cloud run instances are separate things from Google IAMs... Therefore my solution is:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "member" {
  location = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  project  = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
  service  = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member   = "allUsers"
}
```